# Is it possible to plot 3 variables with a common column in 2D with OCTAVE, without the common column in the plot itself?

Tags: octave

I have the following data set, both have one same variable "time". Can I plot B and C against each other?

(this is an extract of the full set)

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-10-26 00:07:20 | 0.68 | 0.0 |
| 2020-10-26 00:12:20 | 0.77 | 0.1 |
| 2020-10-26 00:37:20 | 1.1 | 1.2 |
| 2020-10-26 01:27:20 | 0.51 | 0.0 |
| 2020-10-26 03:42:21 | 0.9 | -0.3 |
| 2020-10-26 04:42:21 | -1.3 | 0.3 |

With the function plotyy(A,B,A,C) I get a nice plot with two y axes and one common x axes. What I want to do if posible, is one of the following two things:

1.- Plot B vs C  with A as the second "y" axis.
2.- Plot B vs C, with respect to time without showing the second Y axis.

[plotyy result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ei1FL.png)

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by 'against' or 'vs'. Typically when people say 'x' against 'y' they mean one is the x axis and the other is the y axis. At the moment as it's written I can interpret your request in multiple ways that contradict each other.

Comment: In what form is your data? Is each column of your table a separate variable, or do you somehow have a single cell array with those columns?

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking into this, yes I want to plot B vs C or C vs B. I want the plot with respect to "A", so as time advances I get a new intersection point between B and C. I want the common axes to be the second "Y axis" and not be on the "X axis"

Answer (score 0):

Although as one of the comments on you question states it’s hard to interpret which ordering you want, the second question seems like it simply can be done with:

`plot(C,B)`

This uses C for the horizontal axis. If I have interpreted wrong, simply switch B and C.

For your first question it is again difficult to tell exactly what you mean. As with your `plotyy(A,B,A,C)` example, you are plotting two variables `B` and `C` against a common x-axis variable, and that is generally the normal usage case.  You can, however, choose any variables you wish for the `plotyy(x1,y1,x2,y2)` inputs.  What your request is missing, if you are using A as y2, is what variable you want to use as x2 for that variable. E.g., you can try

`plotyy(C,B,C,A)`

or

`plotyy(B,C,B,A)`

to maintain a common x axis variable.  You can also try other combinations that don't have a common x axis variable, such as `plotyy(C,B,B,A)`, but I believe that would make interpreting the data rather awkward.